# Successfully registered COM DLL, but can't use class methods

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com

I registered a COM DLL using **regasm.exe**, and now I'm trying to write a VBA script that uses a class from the DLL.  The DLL is `ExcelDataReaderLibrary.dll`.  In the C# source, the class is described as follows (includes code from [this library](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Excel;

namespace ExcelDataReaderLibrary
{
    public class ExcelDataReader
    {
        public void readSheet(string filePath,string sheetName,string outPath)
        {
            // code for method here
        }
    }
}
```

My **assembly.cs** file includes the following:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

[assembly: Guid("b1e78f8f-9ab0-46d8-beac-b843656aacdb")]
```

When I open the VBA Editor and go to References, I see a reference for `ExcelDataReaderLibrary`.  Note that the file associated with this reference is **ExcelDataReaderLibrary.tlb**, not **ExcelDataReaderLibrary.dll**.  After I check this reference,  I want to create and use an `ExcelDataReader` object in VBA as follows:

```
Sub x()    
 Dim xyz As New ExcelDataReaderLibrary.ExcelDataReader
 xyz.readSheet "c:\mypath\testfile.xlsx", "Sheet1", "c:\outputPath"
End Sub
```

The object is successfully created, but `readSheet` gives this error:

```
Automation error
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Also, there is Intellisense for the `ExcelDataReaderLibrary` namespace, but there is no Intellisense for the `ExcelDataReader` object.  I guess my class is registered but not its method--do I have to do something different with the Guid?  How can I call the method from my VBA code?

Comment: You forgot the /codebase option in your Regasm.exe command.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, that was it.  Thank you.  But I still don't have Intellisense for the class--I'd like to see the methods/function headers and properties.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

For the first part of your question, the problem is that `mscoree.dll` needs to find your assembly from the location/context of the calling process, and your object's assembly is not usually in a folder that your process (technically, .NET fusion) will look in. To tell .NET where to find the assembly, you have two options:

- Use the `/codebase` parameter of `REGASM` (as Hans mentioned), which leaves a hint on the registry that points to the assembly's location; or
- Strong-sign your assembly and add it to the GAC, where `mscoree.dll` will always look and find it.

Notice that all the dependencies of your assembly must be equally "findable".

I must warn you that Microsoft very sternly discourages people from using the `/codebase` technique. They argue that it is designed as a development/debugging technique and that it should not be used in production mode. I'm not sure I fully understand their rationale. You should probably look into the documentation for `REGASM` and other references in MSDN and make up your own mind about this. I don't personally find adding my objects to the GAC any more onerous than using `/codebase`.

On the second part of your question, about not getting IntelliSense: your problem is that, by default, COM type libraries generated by .NET expose pure `dispinterface`s (they implement only `IDispatch`, and the type library won't even list the `dispinterface` members). In VB6 terminology, your classes are exposed as `object`s, and all method names and parameters must be determined at run-time.

The generation of the COM class is controlled by an attribute applied to your class, called [`ClassInterfaceAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.classinterfaceattribute.aspx).

Here are the options:

- `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch`: This is the default and so it applies currently to your class. Your class is exposed as a pure dispinterface, and can only be late-bound. No IntelliSense. The TLB doesn't even list the dispinterface members, so a late-bound client cannot ever cache any details about what your class exposes.

This allows maximum flexibility to add, change and remove members with impunity, at least insofar as not hard-crashing the client is concerned. I call this "scripting mode".

- `ClassInterfaceType.None`: This is the stricter mode, that asks you to expose your object more explicitly, kind of like you would have done in IDL/C++. You are expected to declare one of more interfaces with the methods that you want to expose, and make the class explicitly inherit from the interface(s). If you inherit from more than one interface, the first one will be picked as the `[default]` interface, but you should probably designate one explicitly via the `ComDefaultInterfaceAttribute`. If you don't inherit from any interface, your CoClass will inherit straight from IDispatch. (All .NET classes exposed as COM objects are exposed via IDispatch).

This is my preferred mode, but I'm more of a traditionalist when it comes to COM programming. You do get IntelliSense, as long as you do declare and inherit explicitly from an Interface. Obviously, you only get to call the members listed in the Interface. I call this "Strict mode" or "IDL mode".

- `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` This produces a COM interface automatically for you, one that includes all the details of the methods you are exposing. That means you get IntelliSense and you don't have to worry about creating an explicit interface. However, versioning is a royal pain. You have to be very careful to stop all clients before recompiling and/or re-registering your object, or you will be in a world of hurt if your method signatures changed in any way. I call this "VB6 mode", because to me it looks a lot like what VB6 did for you (COM versioning on VB6 is also a royal pain).

Microsoft also strongly discourages people from using `AutoDual`, I suppose because changes to the generated interface can happen more easily without you noticing. I haven't actually had a chance to use it yet, but I'm not sure that it is that much more dangerous than `None`.

*In summary*: If you want to get IntelliSense, you need to apply to your class either `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` (and put your methods in an interface that you explicitly implement), or `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]`. Either way, you have to be very careful to stop your clients (and maybe even "removing" and "re-adding" the references) before making changes to your assembly.