# Import Class from DLL VBA

Tags: vba, dll, qr-code

I have an (unregistered) DLL which I could access in VBA as follows:

```
Declare Function IBarcodeReader Lib "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\interop\zxing.dll" () As Long
```

Problem is, that this works for functions/subs, but I want to access a class contained in the DLL.

Background:
Trying to read QRCodes embedded in a pdf. Will convert PDF to Bitmap and then use the following library in VBA:
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

Comment: are the dll classes public?

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Decode_QR_Code_From_File()
   Dim reader As IBarcodeReader
   Dim res As Result

   Set reader = New BarcodeReader

   reader.options.PossibleFormats.Add BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE

   Set res = reader.DecodeImageFile("D:\Barcodes\QrCodes\www.png")

End Function
```

.

```
Function Decode_QR_Code_From_Byte_Array()
   Dim reader As IBarcodeReader
   Dim rawRGB(1000) As Byte
   Dim res As Result

   Set reader = New BarcodeReader

   reader.options.PossibleFormats.Add BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE

   Rem TODO: load bitmap data to byte array rawRGB
   Set res = reader.DecodeImageBytes(rawRGB, 10, 10, BitmapFormat.BitmapFormat_Gray8)

End Function
```

.

```
Function Encode_To_QR_Code_To_File()
   Dim writer As IBarcodeWriter
   Dim qrCodeOptions As QrCodeEncodingOptions
   Dim pixelDataResult As PixelData

   Set qrCodeOptions = New QrCodeEncodingOptions
   Set writer = New BarcodeWriter
   writer.Format = BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE
   Set writer.options = qrCodeOptions
   qrCodeOptions.Height = 100
   qrCodeOptions.Width = 100
   qrCodeOptions.CharacterSet = "UTF-8"
   qrCodeOptions.Margin = 10
   qrCodeOptions.ErrorCorrection = ErrorCorrectionLevel_H

   writer.WritePngToFile "Test", "D:\interop_qrcode.png"

   Rem Or:

   Set pixelDataResult = writer.Write("Test")

End Function
```

.

```
Function Decode_QR_Code_From_File_CreateObject()
   Dim reader As IBarcodeReader
   Dim res As Result

   Set reader = CreateObject("ZXing.Interop.Decoding.BarcodeReader")

   reader.options.PossibleFormats.Add BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE

   Set res = reader.DecodeImageFile("D:\Barcodes\QrCodes\www.png")

End Function
```

Source: [Using ZXing.Net with VBA](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/wiki/Using-ZXing.Net-with-VBA-(COM-Interop))

---

**Edit**:

re: registering DLL to be able to use Class methods

Have a seen/tried these suggestions:

- [How to register a C# or VB.Net DLL](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/register-dll.html)
- ["Successfully registered COM DLL, but can't use class methods"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703249/successfully-registered-com-dll-but-cant-use-class-methods)
- [VBA importing COM-registered dll and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811067/8112776)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This only works if I add the DLL as a reference in the project - otherwise it won't recognize the IBarcodeReader class. I will only be able to add the DLL as a reference if I can register this, which I'm afraid I'm not able to. Question is, is it possible to add this class in the way I described in my post.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I'm not able to register the dll which is why I'm asking for this workaround

Answer (score 0):

The question is unnecessary when ZXing.Net is registered correctly. [Using ZXing.Net with VBA](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/wiki/Using-ZXing.Net-with-VBA-(COM-Interop)) describes now in detail how to register ZXing.Net for use with VBA.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30689457)